# Counting checkboxes in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

So I have a JFrame with checkboxes in a JPanel. I want to count the amount of selected checkboxes and then multiply that amount by a number and to then be printed on the screen. Any suggestions on how to do this? I want to use an array to store the checkboxes, and then search through the array and see which ones are checked. Then count that number of checked boxes so it can then be used for whatever I needed to do. How can I fix my code?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.*;


public class FYFGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    Container cont = getContentPane();
    private GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(6,2);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    JCheckBox s1 = new JCheckBox("Mowing",false);
    JCheckBox s2 = new JCheckBox("Edging",false);
    JCheckBox s3 = new JCheckBox("Trimming",false);
    JCheckBox s4 = new JCheckBox("Blowing",false);
    JCheckBox s5 = new JCheckBox("Mulch",false);
    JCheckBox s6 = new JCheckBox("Hedges",false);
    JCheckBox s7 = new JCheckBox("Pruning Trees", false);
    JCheckBox s8 = new JCheckBox("Landscaping",false);
    JCheckBox s9 = new JCheckBox("Weeding", false);
    JCheckBox s10 = new JCheckBox("Leaf Removal", false);
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("What services would you like?");
    JLabel Sqft = new JLabel("How many Sq. feet?");
    JTextField area = new JTextField(4);
    JButton exit =  new JButton("Exit");
    JButton calculate = new JButton("Calculate");

    public FYFGUI()
    {
        super("FrontYard Fairways");
        cont.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cont.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        cont.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        cont.add(panel3, BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel.add(lbl);
        panel.add(s1);
        panel.add(s2);
        panel.add(s3);
        panel.add(s4);
        panel.add(s5);
        panel.add(s6);
        panel.add(s7);
        panel.add(s8);
        panel.add(s9);
        panel.add(s10);
        panel2.add(exit);
        panel2.add(calculate);
        panel3.add(Sqft);
        panel3.add(area);
        calculate.addActionListener(this);
        exit.addActionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if(source == exit)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
//This is where the question comes........
        // Get the number of check boxes selected and calculate prices. //SO,here is basically what I want to do....though this is wrong how do I fix this?
JCheckBox[] boxes = {s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10};
        int count;
        for(int i = 0; i < boxes.length; ++i){
            if(boxes[i].isSelected()){
                ++count;
            }

        // Get the sq ft and calculate prices
        // Use the above to calculate hours required
        // Return the total price of service + sqft + hours

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         FYFGUI frame = new FYFGUI();
         frame.setVisible(true);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(FYFGUI.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setSize(800,500);
         frame.setResizable(false);

    }


}
```

Comment: yes, by reading the java docs. all you need to do is parse the componenthierachy from the frame and process the single components

Comment: I don't understand. Any examples?

Comment: 1.) i think you meant `Checkbox`. `JCombobox` can't be selected. 2. ) read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29 . Basically all components in the frame form a tree (frame is the root). Traverse this tree and check if the component is a checkbox. Though using a listener would be a lot easier

Comment: But how do I count the number of selected checkboxes? Lets assume that everything needed like ActionListeners are there. I need a function to count the number of checkboxes selected.

Comment: Use JCheckbox#isSelected(), place all of your components with a collection (java.util.ArrayList).  Your algorithm would traverse the collection and count the select.

Comment: So it would look like this?

Comment: @MadProgrammer "JCombobox can't be selected".

Comment: @MadProgrammer ffs **read** the comment and **then** complain. It explicitly says: "JCombobox can't be selected". Notice something? right, `JCheckBox` isn't even mentioned. sry, but this is getting a bit annoying.

Comment: ComboBox was never mentioned in the question...

Comment: @Paul Sorry, read it as checkbox, but suggesting the op use a api that's 20 years out of date is not really a good idea either

Comment: @MadProgrammer i know this is out of date. But atleast as i understood ops question i, this was what he asked for

Comment: @Paul Where was combobox mentioned anywhere in the OP's question?  And, `JComboBox` can actually be selected, but limits the selection to a single entry...

Comment: @MadProgrammer i made the same mistake you made ^^. And for the selection: theres a bit of a difference between having a selected element of a list and a selected checkbox.

Comment: This is a java question. Not javascript. Plz only comment on the question.

Comment: @user2476208 We are talking Java and discussing if there is a better way to achieve your desired results

Answer (score 0):

If you make an array out of all of your checkboxes, you can simply loop through them and count however many are activated. The code might look something like this, but with an array of them for simplicity:

```
package jcheckboxtester;
/**
 * @author Miharu461
 */
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
public class JCheckBoxTester extends JFrame {
    public JCheckBoxTester() {
        setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setSize(200, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Number Selected: 0");
        label.setBounds(0, 40, 200, 25);

        box.setBounds(0, 0, 25, 25);
        getContentPane().add(box);
        box.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            int count = 0;
            if(box.isSelected()) 
                count++;

            label.setText("Number Selected: " + count);
        });

        getContentPane().add(label);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new JCheckBoxTester().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Looks like you have one CheckBox. I am looking for an answer relative to my code. I am just learning about GUI and Action events. What would the array look like? My issue is putting these components into the array and then sorting through them to count the number of checked boxes. I cannot figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: `JCheckBox[] boxes = {new JCheckBox(), new JCheckBox(), new JCheckBox()};`  would make an array of said number of checkboxes. Since you already have them made, just replace `new JCheckBox()` with that name. For looping to check if they're selected, look at the code I wrote above. just use `isSelected()` in a loop of your array and count them as such. Then revisit your JLabel or whatever puts out the number and correct it to the new number.

Comment: ok so I edited my code with an array and for loop however it is wrong. You have gotten me closer to the solution, still not there. Can you look at my code and tell whats wrong with the loop?

Comment: Can you at least describe what is still wrong? If you've set up your loop...I don't see any code that acknowledges the changes. All you have is a counter. I don't see anywhere from skimming your code that you do anything but add checkboxes that are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Add an ActionListener to each JCheckBox (you can use the same instance of ActionListener). Each time the listener is triggered, check which JChechBox was selected (either compare the `source` or the `actionCommand` of the `ActionEvent`)

Based on the selected state of the `JCheckBox` (that was actioned), either add or subtract the required amount from the total.

This way, you have a running tally in real time. Now if you are clever, there are ways you can automate this, so all you have to do is provide some text and a value (and maybe a model) to something like a custom `Action`, and it can take car of it for you

See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class FYFGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    Container cont = getContentPane();
    private GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(6, 2);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    JCheckBox s1 = new JCheckBox("Mowing", false);
    JCheckBox s2 = new JCheckBox("Edging", false);
    JCheckBox s3 = new JCheckBox("Trimming", false);
    JCheckBox s4 = new JCheckBox("Blowing", false);
    JCheckBox s5 = new JCheckBox("Mulch", false);
    JCheckBox s6 = new JCheckBox("Hedges", false);
    JCheckBox s7 = new JCheckBox("Pruning Trees", false);
    JCheckBox s8 = new JCheckBox("Landscaping", false);
    JCheckBox s9 = new JCheckBox("Weeding", false);
    JCheckBox s10 = new JCheckBox("Leaf Removal", false);
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("What services would you like?");
    JLabel Sqft = new JLabel("How many Sq. feet?");
    JTextField area = new JTextField(4);
    JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
    JLabel tallyLabel = new JLabel("$0.00");

    private double tally;

    public FYFGUI() {
        super("FrontYard Fairways");
        cont.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cont.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        cont.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        cont.add(panel3, BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel.add(lbl);
        panel.add(s1);
        panel.add(s2);
        panel.add(s3);
        panel.add(s4);
        panel.add(s5);
        panel.add(s6);
        panel.add(s7);
        panel.add(s8);
        panel.add(s9);
        panel.add(s10);
        panel2.add(exit);
        panel2.add(tallyLabel);
        panel3.add(Sqft);
        panel3.add(area);
        exit.addActionListener(this);

        s1.addActionListener(this);
        s2.addActionListener(this);
        s3.addActionListener(this);
        s4.addActionListener(this);
        s5.addActionListener(this);
        s6.addActionListener(this);
        s7.addActionListener(this);
        s8.addActionListener(this);
        s9.addActionListener(this);
        s10.addActionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == exit) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (source instanceof JCheckBox) {
            JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox) source;
            // I'd use a Map of some kind as a lookup
            if ("Mowing".equals(cb.getText())) {
                updateTally(cb, 10d);
            } else if ("Edging".equals(cb.getText())) {
                updateTally(cb, 15d);
            } else if ("Trimming".equals(cb.getText())) {
                updateTally(cb, 10d);
            } else if ("Blowing".equals(cb.getText())) {
                updateTally(cb, 10d);
            } else if ("Mulch".equals(cb.getText())) {
                updateTally(cb, 20d);
            } else if ("Hedges".equals(cb.getText())) {
                updateTally(cb, 15d);
            } else if ("Pruning Trees".equals(cb.getText())) {
                updateTally(cb, 25d);
            } else if ("Landscaping".equals(cb.getText())) {
                updateTally(cb, 35d);
            } else if ("Weeding".equals(cb.getText())) {
                updateTally(cb, 100d);
            } else if ("Leaf Removal".equals(cb.getText())) {
                updateTally(cb, 10d);
            }

            tallyLabel.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(tally));
        }
    }

    protected void updateTally(JCheckBox cb, double amount) {
        // You could also add a loading based on area here...
        if (cb.isSelected()) {
            tally += amount;
        } else {
            tally -= amount;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                FYFGUI frame = new FYFGUI();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Now, personally, I'd prefer to use the `Action` API, these are self contained units of work which are self configuring.

```
public class JobAction extends AbstractAction {

    private JobModel model;
    private double amount;

    public JobAction(JobModel model, String text, double amount) {
        this.model = model;
        this.amount = amount;
        putValue(NAME, text);
        putValue(SELECTED_KEY, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object value = getValue(SELECTED_KEY);
        if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            boolean selected = (boolean) value;
            if (selected) {
                model.addJob(getValue(NAME).toString(), amount);
            } else {
                model.removeJob(getValue(NAME).toString(), amount);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In this case, the `JobModel` simply desribes the actions which can occur, in this case add and removal of a job

```
public interface JobModel {
    public void addJob(String text, double amount);
    public void removeJob(String text, double amount);
}
```

(This makes me tempted to make a `Job` interface which contains the text and amount, but that's me)

I prefer to work with interfaces where I can, it makes the code more flexible and restricts other areas of the code so they can only perform certain actions, but that's me.

You would then be able to configure your buttons using something like...

```
JobModel model = new DefaultJobModel(); // You'll need to create this
panel.add(new JCheckBox(new JobAction(model, "Mowing", 10d)));
```

You'd also need to consider providing some-kind of observer pattern (listener) on the model which can used to trigger notifications when the model is changed.

Take a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Comment: I am just learning how to us GUI and Action Events. Your solutions seems a bit advanced. Though it would be nice to do that, however I am just trying to get my bearings on the question at hand. Examples are easier to understand.

Comment: Good, start by reading the tutorials, which contain examples ;)

Comment: Also, using an ActionListener is no more or less complicated the using an array or collection and interacting through it

Comment: StackOverFlow is usually the last place I go to look for answers. Obviously I have tried to find some research about the specific question I am asking with examples. So far no answers to my question. This must be tough for ppl to answer, as I have gotten nothing related to what I am asking. I have edited the question for a more specific answer. Can you look at my code and maybe tell me why my array and loop is wrong?

Comment: @user2476208 This is good, you should also add what research you have done and why it hasn't helped you so we don't cover old ground ;)